# Contact stress of bearing surfaces

Tags: stress-testing, finite-element-analysis

This is my first post to this forum. :)

I am searching for information on how finite element code (abaqus /ansys) could be used to model the contact stress behaviour between 2 bearing surfaces?

The key point is that there is an additional hard coating n both surfaces so as to reduce wear.

How would one model this additional hard layer?

Would this hard layer be represented by an additional layer of elements with a higher elastic modulus?

Thanks
B

Comment: Are you sure this is on-topic here?

Comment: Ask on [Engineering SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can idealize the hard coating by using an extra layer in case you have solids in case that the thickness is high enough to be considered.

Comment: But what property definitions can be used to define the so called stiffness property of the coating. It is well understood that young’s modulus E does not change from core to surface